# How can i get the name parameter defined in get_header?

Tags: wp-head, custom-header

For example, on my blog pages i use `get_header('blog');`, but i don't want to create a new header template called **header-blog.php**, because i just want to make a small adjustments. Is it possible to somehow get this name parameter in my **header.php** file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an action `get_header` that you can use. In your theme’s `functions.php`, register a callback for that action:

```
add_action( 'get_header', function( $name ) {
    add_filter( 'current_header', function() use ( $name ) {
        // always return the same type, unlike WP
        return (string) $name;
    });
});
```

You could also write a little helper class that you can reuse:

```
class Template_Data {

    private $name;

    public function __construct( $name ) {

        $this->name = (string) $name;
    }

    public function name() {

        return $this->name;
    }
}

add_action( 'get_header', function( $name ) {
    add_filter( 'current_header', [ new Template_Data( $name ), 'name' ] );
});
```

In your `header.php`, you get the current part/name with:

```
$current_part = apply_filters( 'current_header', '' );
```

You can do the same with `get_footer`, `get_sidebar` and `get_template_part_{$slug}`.

Comment: nice trick! Would be much simpler if WP would just add this var to `$args` so it's available inside `header.php` natively. Added this proposal to trac: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51726#ticket